# How to print full path of OSX applications

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, which

I would like to get the full path of OSX applications like Safari, Chrome, iTerm...

As I see, OSX packages have a specific folder structure, and so, the main binaries will end up in `/Applications/*AppName*.app/Contents/MacOS/`

For example: iTerm full path would be: `/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm`

Is this guaranteed for all applications, or is there a tool like "which" that can print the specific path?

Comment: It's pretty much guaranteed, but only down so far as `/Contents/MacOS/` After that you can never be certain that the executable is always going to be *exactly* the same name as the package.

Comment: Thanks, I eventually ended up using: locate "/Applications*/Contents/MacOS*/iTerm"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the command "locate".   The first time you use it, the system will have to generate a database, from that point on, you'll be good to go.

To set up the DB, run this:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist
```

Then, to run a locate (once the DB is created... it can take a while), run:

```
locate <search pattern>
```

Comment: Thanks @tomlester, as I mentioned above in comments, this is what I actually ended up doing: `locate "/Applications*/Contents/MacOS*/AppName"`